# Add additional Network constants to wp-config.php dynamically

Tags: multisite, installation, wp-config, network-admin, customization

When starting with a fresh Network install, the first step is a single site install that has one additional line in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

After that we have to go to `Tools > Network Setup`, enter some details like network name and super admin email and finally hit the button to run the setup.

The next step the pops up is actually two steps:

1. Add *additional* constants to your `wp-config.php` file

   ```
   define( 'MULTISITE', true );
   define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
   define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );
   define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
   define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );
   define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );
   ```
2. Add some rules to your `.htaccess` file.

As I don't do single site installs (no reason for that anymore), I'd like to add those constants dynamically to my `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
if ( SOME_CHECK_IF_STEP-1_WAS_PASSED )
{
    define( 'MULTISITE', true );
    define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
    define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com' );
    define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
    define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );
    define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );
}
```

So I don't have to go to the `wp-config.php` each time and edit it again.

The *1st* thing that came into my mind was to check the DB for the `{$wpdb->prefix}sitemeta` table, but I don't want to do an additional query on each site load. The *2nd* thing I thought of was to check if the `blogs.dir` already exists, but that's not the case.

> **Question:** How can I indicate that I already passed the first step of the network setup in way that doesn't has a massive overhead or decreases performance.

Comment: You shouldnt try to automate everything: http://i.imgur.com/OoF9Md7.png

Comment: it's actually unbelievable the process is still the same while more and more WP installation become multisite

Comment: @ÜnsalKorkmaz If you've seen my config setup, you'll understand that this is only one more step forward. Next thing: Grunt `wp-config` generator.

Comment: I can't understand why you would need to check if a condition exists for every page load and then define constants. You are with running a multisite set-up or you're not.

If you're talking about automating WordPress set-up you can look into something like YeoPress https://github.com/wesleytodd/YeoPress

Comment: @kingkool68 Easy. Because I don't want to uncomment/comment those constants each time I set up a network install. It's no overhead and the step simply is unnecessary. And no, I'm not talking about automating WP setup. Btw: Yeoman uses Grunt for tasks (which I mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but if you would need to find such a solution, I would probably try to do it in the following way by adding a script into the `if ( SOME_CHECK_IF_STEP-1_WAS_PASSED )` condition you've described above, that would:

- check the DB for the `{$wpdb->prefix}sitemeta` table;
- if it does not exist -> return false;
- if it does exists -> add a WP cron job to rewrite `wp-config.php` -> return true.

The WP cron job would rewrite the `wp-config.php` to eliminate the check completely.

This way, you only have an additional DB request until the network is set up and the cron job did its magic.

*Note sure this is worth the effort, though... ;)*

Comment: BTW, the script *could* change the `wp-config.php` file directly, but I suppose that it would be locked at that point...

Comment: That cron job idea is funny :) Thanks for that. Btw, you can [edit] your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Inspect `wp-admin/network.php` and `wp-admin/includes/schema.php` files. You can create a condition based on **WP_INSTALLING_NETWORK**

Update:

```
if (is_admin()){
    /* First Step */
    if (!defined( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE')){
            $current_wp_config = file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');

            $my_defines = "/* First we put WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE  */\r\n" .
                    "define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true); \r\n";

            $current_wp_config = str_replace("/* That's all, stop editing", $my_defines . "/* That's all, stop editing", $current_wp_config);       
            file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php', $current_wp_config);   
    }   
    /* Second Step */
    if (!defined("WP_DEFINES_IMPORTED") && defined("WP_INSTALLING_NETWORK") && $_POST){
        $current_wp_config = file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');

        $my_defines = "/* Now we define */\r\n" .
            "define('WP_DEFINES_IMPORTED', true); \r\n" .
            "define('MULTISITE', true); \r\n".
            "define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true); \r\n".
            "define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '". get_clean_basedomain() . "'); \r\n".
            "define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '". parse_url(  trailingslashit( get_option( 'home' ) ), PHP_URL_PATH ) . "'); \r\n".
            "define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); \r\n".
            "define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); \r\n";

        $current_wp_config = str_replace("/* That's all, stop editing", $my_defines . "/* That's all, stop editing", $current_wp_config);       
        file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php', $current_wp_config);   
    }
}
```

1. put this to mu-plugins folder.
2. fresh wp install
3. go to admin panel
4. click to tools
5. click to network setup
6. run the setup
7. ???
8. profit!!!

[image]

Comment: I already checked that. Point is that `wp-load.php` pulls in `wp-config.php` earlier, so `WP_INSTALLING_NETWORK` won't be defined. But even if it would be available, it's only available during network setup. What would I do to leave the constants in _after_ the installation has run?

Comment: No.. you should use a function to execute once and write your defines to wp-config.php file once. You can think it like register_activation_hook

Comment: [`index.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/index.php#L17) pulls `./wp-blog-header.php`), which then pulls [`wp-load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-blog-header.php#L12) and from there [`wp-config.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-load.php#L29) is called. An [overview can be found here](http://www.rarst.net/images/wordpress_core_load.png). `admin.php` itself gets called before `setup.php` and `network.php` (and calls `wp-load.php` itself at the beginning), so config has been running already.

Comment: And as `WP_INSTALLING_NETWORK` gets `define()` without checking if it is already `defined()`, I would create an `Fatal Error` there. Please proof me wrong and give it a test. :)

Comment: I wrote code.. i proved you wrong.

Comment: Ehm... Ünsal, are you sure that it's a good idea to make the `wp-config.php` writable? 8)

Comment: are u trolling me?

Comment: No Ünsal, I'm not. I'm even ignoring the fact that I could take the off-topic comic strip above as trolling or just rude. I'm searching for a solution. Period. But having a writable `wp-config.php` file is a security risk. Consider that you got all important details in there. I showed you that there's no way that this would work (without having a writable config file). What I'm searching for is an **indicator** (which doesn't slow down the system) that I can check against and use as switch. Everything else won't work.

Answer (score -1):

If your setup is the same every time (subdomain install), then you may be able to paste the entire chunk in your first step:

`define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', true );`

Comment: As you can see in the question, I am quite aware of the needed constants. What I am searching for is a **reliable indicator** if the setup already passed step 1, nothing else. Please see the highlighted actual question at bottom. Thanks for your efforts tough.

Comment: My answer was to challenge whether you even need the indicator at all, but rather rely on the server variable to serve the correct `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` constant that WordPress gives you after completing the internal setup.